# How to find first unused cells on a filtered column

Tags: excel, vba

I've a range filtered, and I can mange theme, but I can't find the first unused cell OUTSIDE of the filter range.

Look at the code of my initior class:

```
Public Sub init(rowList As Range, Optional hasHeader As Boolean = True)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Set aa.rowsList = rowList

    For i = 1 To aa.rowsList.Areas.count
        k = k + aa.rowsList.Areas(i).rows.count
    Next

    If k < aa.blockSize Then
        k = k + aa.blockSize
    Else
        k = k + aa.blockSize * 2
    End If

    ReDim aa.rowDataArray(0 To k) As Range

    i = 0
    For Each rw In aa.rowsList
        If i = 0 And hasHeader And aa.rowHeader Is Nothing Then
            Set aa.rowHeader = rw
        Else
            Set aa.rowDataArray(i) = rw
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    k = aa.rowsList.rows(65536).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set aa.rowDataArray(i) = aa.rowsList.rows(k).EntireRow

    Set rw = Nothing

    aa.count = i
    aa.rowCursor = -1

End Sub
```

RowList is: `myWorkSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).rows`

So it my filter return just 1 row (the header) the instruction        `aa.rowsList.rows(65536).End(xlUp).Row '--> 1`

But I need to identify the first unused row, that could be 2544 (the sheet has many rows).

Any idea more efficient than a loop trough the all the cells of a column?

P.S.
If I remove the filter it's work, but it isn't correct because the filter is applied outside the class.

Comment: Dom, I would recommend using the `UsedRange` property. It returns a range object from the most top-left to bottom-right filled cells. After that can just do `ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1`

Comment: Please note that recent Excel versions have more than `rows(65536)`. Instead use `rows(rows.count)`.

Comment: thank's J VBA, I'll try at soon.
at now, maybe I solved with:
k = aa.rowsList.Worksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.count + 1
do you think is a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
Public Function FindLastUnusedCell(rowList As Range)
    'Count the total rows   (Office 2003 has 65500, Office and up has 1048576)
    totalrows = Rows.Count
    FindLastUnusedCell = Cells(totalrows, rowList.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End Function
```

I hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: thak's Raul! 
my issue is related to the filter applied non about the rowcout, because with the filter applied (with no row selected) your instruction return row 2 :-(

Comment: have you tried with Subtotal formula? if you do a Filter you can get the Count and find the las unused cell adding a +1, example:  =Subtotal(2, {Your column filtered here})